# Laravel 5 $request->input vs Input::get

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Just wondering what is the difference between:

```
$username = $request->input('username');
```

and

```
$username = Input::get('username');
```

Comment: Nothing they are exactly the same, except for the fact that `Input::get` is deprecated (it's not mentioned anywhere but one can assume Request is the prefered way when reading the docs) since it's not mentioned anywhere in the docs with laravel 5.0 and higher.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests check on this

Comment: laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests only mentions Input::get, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests only mentions $request->input

Comment: Note that `Input` facade was replaced with `Request` in Laravel 6 (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#the-input-facade).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference, the facade Input calls the input method from request. But `Input::get` is deprecated, prefer the `$request->input` instead of `Input::get`

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Http\Request
 */
class Input extends Facade
{
    /** 
     * Get an item from the input data.
     *
     * This method is used for all request verbs (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE)
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed   $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function get($key = null, $default = null)
    {   
        return static::$app['request']->input($key, $default);
    }   

    /** 
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {   
        return 'request';
    }   
}
```

Comment: The code I posted is the Facade Input which is in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.php`

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same but this one kind laravel inbuilt Functionality To make a proper use of laravel.

You can use both way but following things are made only in INPUT. Just a look.

1. `Input::has('name')`
2. `Input::all()`
3. `Input::only('username', 'password')`
4. `Input::except('credit_card')`
5. `Input::get('products.0.name')`

And also this on

```
Input::get('username');
```

So that make things easy for as.

That other thing we have to do more code if we use this.

```
$request->input('username')
```

Hope You understand.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not true, Input is just a Facade for the request, as well as Request is a Facade for the request, which means that Input uses the methods of the request, if you want to use a Facade for practicality, you should use the Facade Request instead of Input, for example, `Request::all(); Request::has('name');`

Comment: @JairoCorrea is right. We can even use $data=$request->all() to fetch all the data from the view.